# Dependency issue within two projects that use same lib

Tags: go, dependency-management, dep

I have two projects:

```
/myproject
/sharedproject
```

both of them are managed by dep, I have execute `go get -u github.com/golang/dep/cmd/dep` in order to have latest dep version, and run `dep ensure` on both projects.

When I run `myproject` I get following error:

```
cannot use op (type *"myproject/vendor/github.com/go-openapi/spec".Operation) as type *"sharedproject/vendor/github.com/go-openapi/spec".Operation
```

What is wrong and how to fix this?

Comment: Only vendor dependencies in a binary, not in a library.

Comment: @Adrian, could you please explain this, bc in my vendor I have source code of dependencies libs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the situation is that `sharedproject` vendors the `github.com/go-openapi/spec` dependency while `myproject`
gets both `sharedproject` and `github.com/go-openapi/spec` dependencies from
`GOPATH`.

Now when you refer to `github.com/go-openapi/spec` in `sharedproject`, it refers to
the package inside the vendor directory, which is technically different from the
same package in `GOPATH`, even if both have the same content. So when you pass a
variable of type `*github.com/go-openapi/spec.Operation` from `myproject` to a
function in `sharedproject`, the package of the type differs from what's expected and compilation fails.

To solve this, make sure `sharedproject` is vendored inside `myproject`. When
you do this, `dep ensure` will put a copy of `sharedproject` without its vendor
directory into `myproject`'s vendor directory. After this, both `myproject` and `sharedproject` will use the `github.com/go-openapi/spec` package from `myproject`'s vendor directory.

That does make local development hard if you change `sharedproject` often and want
to immediately use those changes in `myproject` (can't use `dep` till the changes are pushed to the Git remote). I'd work around that by copying
over `sharedproject` into `myproject`'s vendor directory manually without using `dep` (excluding the vendor directory of course). Be careful to not commit those manually copied changes to Git though!